# C# Event Handling Order

Tags: c#, events

The scenario is an event on a buffer, that informs interested classes when there is data available to be collected. The event is fired as soon as new data is written to the buffer. When this is fired, the delegate for the event (in the interested class) starts reading data from the buffer.

My question is, if the event were fired again (before the method had finished reading all the data from the buffer) would the reading method be 'reset' or would the event wait for the method to finish reading the data before calling it again?

Comment: The method will keep going, unless you've coded it to stop early.

Answer (score 2):

The event could only be fired again before the method had finished reading if it were fired on another thread. The event handlers will then (by default) be called again in that separate thread. There's no concept of an existing method being "reset", nor would it wait for the already-running handlers to finish before firing again.

Of course, you could potentially change how the handlers work, or how the event is fired - perhaps ensuring that the event handlers are only called from a single thread, with some sort of queue of events. It's impossible for us to tell whether that's appropriate for your situation though.

Answer (score 0):

Neither, it would execute it alongside (in parallel), if on separate threads - otherwise execution would be blocking anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*Unless* you've put `Application.DoEvents()` in your code (which is a horrible thing to do) then your event won't be interrupted.

In a multithreading scenario, there's the possibility of them running in parallel. I don't use multiple threads and events both at the same time, so I can't really say much about that, but it seems like Jon's covered that one nicely with his answer.